# Is it possible to add pagination to a Woocommerce loop?

Tags: php, loops, pagination, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and need to make a new loop.

This loop is working, however, some key information is left out, I need the number of products per page, and more importantly the pagination is gone, so in this instance I have six products displayed, and everything else is impossible to view
The information I need is in these two actions, however I don't know how to add these actions to my loop!

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>
<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>
```

The loop I have so far is:

```
 <ul class="products">

    <?php

       $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'product',
           'posts_per_page' => 6,
           'product_cat' => 'guys'
       );
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
       if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
           while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
               woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
           endwhile;
       } else {
           echo __( 'No products found' );
       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Is this for your shop page? Another archive? You don't need to set up a new query when you can modify the existing one. WooCommerce pagination is handled by `woocommerce_pagination()` which is sort of a wrapper for `paginate_links()`

Comment: it's for another archive. I'm using AJAX to reload just the product loop on the page.

I have an unordered list with a few product categories, and each will load in a category.php file that replaces the contents of the original product loop with the product loop that has its corresponding `'product_cat' => 'category'`

Comment: I'm studying the `paginate_links()` you mentioned.

I found this bit of code which seems to be the magic:                                    `<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
 <?php
  echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array() ) );
 ?>
</nav>` I'm assuming this would get appended to the loop query in some way?

Comment: wait I think because I'm using AJAX I'm refreshing the  content of the loop, but I'm not reinitializing the global variable $wp_query this variable is what populates the pagination I think. So if I make the variable refresh at the same time, or after the ajax occurs I think it might display! 

I just don't know how to reinitialize PHP variables :(

Comment: nope, back to square one :/

Comment: So you are paginating via ajax?

Comment: I am trying too, and when I ajax the woocommerce loop the pagination does not refresh with it, it just completely dissapears.